# Building a calculator with set of input values and fixed interest rate

Tags: python, for-loop, calculator

Assuming, I am running a weekly business and making profits every week at a constant interest rate of 5% per week and assuming my investment is recursive every week, I want to print all values for first 21 weeks. How do i right a code in python to achieve this?
Note: Investment is recursive, (i.e) every week my investment will be previous investment plus profit made in that week and also I am my rounding off the values and I have written this code but For loop I am struggling to write the logic , could some one help please. I have written the logic /calculations in excel - please check for expected results the excel screenshot.

```
maximum_number_of_weeks = int(input("maximum_number_of_weeks:"))
Initial_investment_Amount = int(input("Enter Initial Investment Amount Value ($) : "))
Interest_rate = float(input("Enter Interest Rate Value (%) : "))
Amount_Earned = Initial_investment_Amount * Interest_rate
Total_Amount_at_Disposal = Initial_investment_Amount + Amount_Earned
print("Total_Amount_at_Disposal ($) : ",Total_Amount_at_Disposal)
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest using a more simple approach:

Amount at disposal = Initial investment * (1 + interest rate) ^ (number of weeks)

```
maximum_number_of_weeks = int(input("maximum_number_of_weeks:"))
Initial_investment_Amount = int(input("Enter Initial Investment Amount Value ($) : "))
Interest_rate = float(input("Enter Interest Rate Value (%) : "))

for week in range(1, maximum_number_of_weeks + 1):
    Total_Amount_at_Disposal = Initial_investment_Amount * (1 + Interest_rate/100) ** week
    print("Total_Amount_at_Disposal ($) : ",round(Total_Amount_at_Disposal, 2))
```

Comment: This doesn't help, because the OP says they "want to print all values for first 21 weeks". In other words, they want to reproduce columns A & B in the spreadsheet.

Comment: Now it prints the value for every week.